# subscribe a Variable you got from a socket

Tags: angular, sockets, observable, subscribe

i try to update my token i get every 30 sec from my socket. But the code i found doesn#t work.
How do i subscribe to a varibale in this chase ?
And if i subscribe does the values always change or just the first time?

**the socket**

```html
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {

  public token =new Observable<any>()
  second;
  socket  = io.connect('http://localhost:3333');
  msg: any;


  getToken() {
    console.log('newToken');
    this.socket.on('newToken', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.token = data.token; 
      this.second = data.second;
      console.log(this.token, this.second);
    });
  }
```

**the component**

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SocketService} from '../../Service/socket.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-token',
  templateUrl: './token.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./token.component.css']
})
export class TokenComponent implements OnInit {

  token;

constructor(
    private socket: SocketService,
  ) {
    this.socket.token.subscribe(res => {
      this.token = res;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.socket.getToken();
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning `SocketService.token` an Observable or just a token?

On this line 
`this.token = data.token;` I expect you to be assigning an Observable. If `data.token` is an Observable, please let us know or type data appropriately.

You can try using a Subject instead.
Try changing your declaration in `SocketService` to 
`public token = new Subject<any>();`

Then in the socket.on callback. Set the token value by `this.token.next(data.token)`